# Phrase "I will not fail you"

Tags: phrases

This phrase "I will not fail you", 
Is it formal or informal?

What are the other words used to convey the same feelings?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "formal" and "informal" in this context. Perhaps you should elaborate on that.

Comment: I mean, where is it suited perfect, in official way(formal) or in friendly manner(informal)?

Comment: A great portion of the English language can be used in both formal (official) and informal (friendly) contexts. I would regard the sentence "I will not fail you" to be among those utterances that would fit just fine into either setting; I wouldn't regard it as [overly stilted](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stilted) in a friendly conversation, nor as [too colloquial](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/colloquial) for a formal speech.

Comment: Thanks J.R. I am feeling lucky that I chose to be on EL&U!

Comment: I think you might enjoy [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) even more, if you haven't been there yet. That site is specifically for people who are learning the English language, and for questions that would be pretty obvious for most native speakers. Had you asked this question there, instead of here, I would have left an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: The above comments make sense. I think the formal / informal classification is perhaps the wrong one to consider here; the serious / light classification makes sense. 'I will not fail you' certainly isn't light banter, and sounds more serious (yes, and admittedly more formal) than 'I won't let you down'.

Comment: I agree that this question is more suited to ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it's informal since *to fail* is regularly used like *to fail **at** something*.
Other ways to say this would be:

> I will not disappoint you
>
> I will rise to your expectations

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the phrase is formal. This phrase has similar meaning:

> I won't let you down